# useDaylightTime() this method in TimeZone.java return wrong answer

Tags: java, timezone, dst

Casablanca is a city of Morocco, actually Morocco use DST, but method useDaylight() return false,on the other side, Roma also use DST and useDaylight() return true
My jdk is 8u362 and my code is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone Rome = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome");
        System.out.println(Rome.useDaylightTime());

        TimeZone Casablanca = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Casablanca");
        System.out.println(Casablanca.useDaylightTime());

    }
```

and the result is

```
true
false
```

I have checked Casablanca and Roma both use DST, why timezone of Casablanca return false

I have tried some other city as timezone, found that some timezone use DST but return false, and other city is normal, can someone tell me why and explain the real mean of method useDaylight()?

Comment: Don’t use `TimeZone`. That class was poorly designed and is long outdated. Use `ZoneId` and `ZoneRules` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: `ZoneId.of("Africa/Casablanca").getRules().previousTransition(Instant.now())` gives us `Transition[Overlap at 2023-03-19T03:00+01:00 to Z]`. It will also tell us about other transitions. Then I guess it’s up to us to interpret whether the time zone uses summer time. The modern date and time API requires us to be more explicit and doesn’t do the interpretation for us. Which I find fair since the question whether some time zone uses summer time really isn’t a simple *yes or no* question.

Answer (score 1):

## Feature, not a bug

You are seeing a feature not a bug.

The Javadoc for `TimeZone#useDaylightTime` says the method may not account for the current rule. The Javadoc goes on to advise:

> Consider calling [observesDaylightTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#observesDaylightTime()) if the current rule should also be taken into account.

Sure enough, we get different results.

```java
System.out.println(
        java.util.TimeZone
                .getTimeZone( "Africa/Casablanca" )
                .useDaylightTime()
);

System.out.println(
        java.util.TimeZone
                .getTimeZone( "Africa/Casablanca" )
                .observesDaylightTime()
);
```

When run:

```
false
true
```

However, that second result is wrong in that **at the current moment Morocco is using *standard time* during Ramadan**. But frankly I cannot parse their intentions as stated in the Javadoc.

And, to confuse matters even more, there is a third method [`inDaylightTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#inDaylightTime(java.util.Date)).

What a mess: Three methods with nearly the same name that return different results. These legacy date-time classes are a train-wreck of bad design, built by people who did not understand date-time handling.

Read on for sane date-time handling with the *java.time* classes.

## Morocco

See the Wikipedia article, [*Daylight saving time in Morocco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco).

Starting in 2008, Morocco annually observed [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (+01:00) until October of 2018. In that month, rather than “fall back” to their standard time (+00:00), the politicians decided to stay on DST (+01:00) year-round (the latest fad among politicians around the world).

On top of that, the politicians in Morocco have been deciding to fall back an hour (+00:00) during the month of [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `TimeZone` class is part of the terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `ZoneId`

Instead of `TimeZone`, you should be using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) & `ZoneOffset`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
```

## `ZoneRules`

From a `ZoneId`, get its set of [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html).

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" );
Instant pointInTime = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant();
Instant now = Instant.now();

ZoneRules rules = z.getRules();
```

## `ZoneOffsetTransition`

Interrogate those rules for recent offset [transitions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html).

```java
List < ZoneOffsetTransition > transitions =
        rules
                .getTransitions()
                .stream()
                .filter( transition -> transition.getInstant().isAfter( pointInTime ) && transition.getInstant().isBefore( now ) )
                .toList();
for ( ZoneOffsetTransition transition : transitions )
{
    System.out.println( "transition = " + transition );
}
```

When run:

```
transition = Transition[Overlap at 2021-04-11T03:00+01:00 to Z]
transition = Transition[Gap at 2021-05-16T02:00Z to +01:00]
transition = Transition[Overlap at 2022-03-27T03:00+01:00 to Z]
transition = Transition[Gap at 2022-05-08T02:00Z to +01:00]
transition = Transition[Overlap at 2023-03-19T03:00+01:00 to Z]
```

We can see the changes back and forth between DST (+01:00) and standard time of an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC as represented here by the letter `Z` (pronounced “Zulu”).

```java
List < ZonedDateTime > zdts =
        List.of(
                LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ,
                LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.MARCH , 30 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ,
                ZonedDateTime.now( z )
        );
for ( ZonedDateTime zdt : zdts )
{
    System.out.println( zdt + " is in DST: " + rules.isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() ) );
}
```

## `isDaylightSavings`

For a few arbitrary points in time, let's ask if that moment is in DST or not.

```java
List < ZonedDateTime > zdts =
        List.of(
                LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ,
                LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.MARCH , 30 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ,
                ZonedDateTime.now( z )
        );
for ( ZonedDateTime zdt : zdts )
{
    System.out.println( zdt + " is in DST: " + rules.isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() ) );
}
```

When run:

```
2023-01-01T00:00+01:00[Africa/Casablanca] is in DST: true
2023-03-30T00:00Z[Africa/Casablanca] is in DST: false
2023-04-19T03:42:56.153413Z[Africa/Casablanca] is in DST: false
```

A couple of sources on the Web say that Ramadan 2023 in Morocco runs from Thursday, 23 March 2023, to Friday, 21 April 2023. Notice the transition I showed above is different, with the fall-back on March 19th rather than the 23rd. I do not know of an explanation. Perhaps the politicians are not strictly using the Ramadan dates for their change in offset. That fall-back is according to the [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) in my implementation of [Java 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_20), which should be fairly fresh.

So as described above, we can see DST is used for most of the year such as on January 1st 2023 in list above. Then for our two March & April dates, DST is *not* used per the Ramadan roll-back to standard time (+00:00).

---

You asked:

> explain the real mean of method useDaylight()?

The modern replacement is [`ZoneRules#isDaylightSavings( Instant instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings(java.time.Instant)).

To quote the Javadoc:

> Checks if the specified instant is in daylight savings.
>
> This checks if the standard offset and the actual offset are the same for the specified instant. If they are not, it is assumed that daylight savings is in operation.
>
> This default implementation compares the actual and standard offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code for [TimeZone](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/TimeZone-source.html).

The `TimeZone` corresponding to `Europe/Rome` is defined as follows (line 539):

```
new SimpleTimeZone(1000 * 3600, "CET", Calendar.MARCH, -1, Calendar.SUNDAY, 2000 * 3600, Calendar.OCTOBER, -1, Calendar.SUNDAY, 3000 * 3600);
```

Where the [4th to 10th arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html#SimpleTimeZone-int-java.lang.String-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-) relate to daylight saving and result in `useDaylightTime()` returning true.

The `TimeZone` corresponding to `Africa/Casablanca` (line 486) is:

```
new SimpleTimeZone(0 * 3600, "GMT")
```

And result in `useDaylightTime()` returning true

So Java defines Europe/Rome as having daylight savings and Africa/Casablanca as not having daylight savings.

The next question is: does this reflect reality?

Java uses the TimeZone ‘historical’ definitions from the global authority, the [Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers](https://www.icann.org/) which [change to reflect reality with different versions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tzdata-versions.html).

According to the above page [Morocco gave up daylight saving in Oct 2018](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-October/000052.html) and this change was reflected in the following versions 11.0.2, 8u201 & 7u211.

Comment: According to [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/morocco) *Morocco is on permanent Daylight Saving Time (DST) most of the year. But for Ramadan, the country sets the clocks back 1 hour, making sunset 1 hour earlier.* Whether this counts as using summer time (DST) I can’t really tell. Also [worlddata.info](https://www.worlddata.info/africa/morocco/timezones.php) mentions clock changes related to DST in March and April this year.

Comment: Yes they never went back at the end of summer 2018. Permanent DST is just moving to the next timezone. DST ≠ Ramadan adjustment, but the Java TimeZone class could actually cope with this.